# Kotlin native platform posix compilation without gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to compile a basic Kotlin/Native program with just the `kotlinc-native` CLI compiler rather than a full Gradle build. However, I cannot get the `platform.posix` library to work, despite compiling on linux for linux.

The source code I am using is:

```
import platform.posix.exit
fun main() {
    println("Should exit with status 10")
    exit(10)
}
```

When compiled with the following `build.gradle.kts` it works fine:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
  linuxX64("native") {
    binaries {
      executable()
    }
  }
}
```

However, when compiled from the command-line with:

```
kotlinc-native test.kt
```

I get:

```
test.kt:1:8: error: unresolved reference: platform
import platform.posix.exit
       ^
test.kt:4:5: error: unresolved reference: exit
    exit(10)
    ^
```

Anyone know how to get Kotlin/Native compilation working fully without using Gradle? Or is there some magic that Gradle does that makes it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Could you please clarify, are you using the compiler built from sources(cloned from https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/kotlin-native) orr downloaded by Gradle(located at ~/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-<host>-<version>/bin/)? For the former case, one have not only to build the compiler by running `./gradlew dist` but also build these platform libraries by `./gradlew distPlatformLibs` before using. The latter one should not require any additional steps.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev not the original poster, but I have the same issue when running using the precompiled release downloaded from: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/download/v1.5.32/kotlin-native-macos-x86_64-1.5.32.tar.gz

Comment: The releases on GitHub (if that is where you got yours from too) don't contain the platform libs. I've put together a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52259/kotlin-native-releases-from-GitHub-don-t-contain-platform-libs

Answer (score 0):

Now version 1.9.0, you just need add `@file:OptIn(kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi::class)` at the top of file.